# Solving two coupled partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to solve the following system of two coupled partial differential equations (both equations equal 0):

[image]

Here, $V$ and $Y$ are functions that only depend on $r$, i.e., $V=V(r)$ and $Y=Y(r)$. $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $k^{-2}$ are just constants, $H^{L\mu}_\mu=0$ and $H^{Li}_i-H^{Lt}_t=0$. I've tried to use DSolve but it doesn't work:

```
DSolve[{2*(3*b - a)*1/r^4*(r^2*v'[r])'' - c*k*1/r^2*(r^2*v'[r])' - 
4*(3*b - a)*1/r^2*(r^2*Y'[r])' + 2*c*k*Y[r] == 0, 2*b*1/r^4*(r^2*v'[r])'' - c*k*1/r^2*(r^2*v'[r])' + 
2*(a - 2*b)*1/r^2*(r^2*Y'[r])' == 0}, {v, Y}, r]
```

Since the prime only works for the pure function, I've switched the initial code to this equivalent one:

```
`DSolve[{2*(3*b - a)*(2 v'[r] + 4 r v''[r] + r^2 v'''[r]) - 
c*k*1/r^2*(2 r v'[r] + r^2 v''[r]) - 
4*(3*b - a)*1/r^2*(2 r Y'[r] + r^2 Y''[r]) + 2*c*k*Y[r] == 0, 
2*b*1/r^4*(2 v'[r] + 4 r v''[r] + r^2 v'''[r]) - 
c*k*1/r^2*(2 r v'[r] + r^2 v''[r]) + 
2*(a - 2*b)*1/r^2*(2 r Y'[r] + r^2 Y''[r]) == 0}, {v, Y}, r] `
```

But still doesn't work.
I don't know much about mathematica and this problem is untractable without numerical methods. Can someone send some help? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have used to try to solve the problem?

Comment: Writing ``(..)'` is wrong syntax. You can use this syntax only if the argument is a function, not an expression. You would have to write: `D[...,r]` or `D[...,{r,2}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for your answer, if you see my edit I did exactly that writing explicitly the derivative, but mathematica doesn't give any answer either.

Comment: Are you sure that a general solution for arbitrary a,b,c,k exists?

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, in some sense the only non arbitrary constants are $k$, which has to do with newton constant, and $\gamma$ which is approximately 2 for a good Newtonian limit of the theory. These equations arise up in studying higher derivatives theories of gravity, you can see for instance https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227237782_Classical_Gravity_with_Higher_Derivatives, and it has a solution of raising and falling Yukawa's potential. However, I can't derive by myself those solutions because I'm doing something wrong in mathematica,

Comment: The equations in LaTex format contain fourth derivatives, but in Mathematica format only third derivatives.  Which is correct?  By the way, these are ODEs, not PDEs.

Comment: In your reduced order expression for v and Y, If I assign values to the constants such as  a=1, b=2, c=-2,k=3, then I obtain a solution in terms of differential roots.  Maybe you can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the NOT coupled equations separately, you will get a result:

DSolve[{2*b*1/r^4*(2 v'[r] + 4 r v''[r] + r^2 v'''[r]) -
c*k*1/r^2*(2 r v'[r] + r^2 v''[r]) +
2*(a - 2*b)*1/r^2*(2 r Y'[r] + r^2 Y''[r]) == 0}, {v}, r]

[image]

DSolve[{2*b*1/r^4*(2 v'[r] + 4 r v''[r] + r^2 v'''[r]) -
c*k*1/r^2*(2 r v'[r] + r^2 v''[r]) +
2*(a - 2*b)*1/r^2*(2 r Y'[r] + r^2 Y''[r]) == 0}, {Y}, r]

[image]